# php file limit when downloading/processing memory limit or mysql

Tags: php, mysql, memory, download

im trying to create a google feed in php

```
$prodquery = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `enabled`='1' ";
```

i run this query and set the header like this

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $name);
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8');
```

then proceed to echo out the rest of the data  but when i go to download the file from the server i just get a network error. so theirs no output telling me why it happend

it gets to about 4mb and stops chrome firefox etc says "failed - network error" is it a memory limit on the server that im missing i increased them all.

i know for sure its not an error in the data causing the script to 500 the page because i have offset the query by a few products and it runs through the point it cuts out

max execution time is set to 600 its barely getting to 20 seconds before the cut out and its always 4mbs

is there a mysql limit of some kind?

Comment: Can you please add a condition to the query to get less records so the filesize would be smaller, just to check if the file is incomplete or built incorrectly.

Comment: yes ive already done that, its nothign to do with the query im 100% sure of this i have offset it to the records that might be causing the issue i.e around 220 and before and after and it still runs through 200 records.

this means it has to be related to file size or  memory